# What does 'look on' mean?

Tags: meaning

> The Swiss bridge is also longer than the so-called "footbridge in the sky." This bridge, built in 2014, is part of the Sochi Sky Park in Russia. It spans 439 meters and includes observation platforms **looking on** the mountains and the Black Sea Coast。
>   [source link](https://learningenglish.voanews.com/a/switzerland-open-worlds-longest-suspension-bridge/3971110.html)

What does *look on* mean in the case highlighted above?

Comment: I would assume that the meaning is that a person can stand on one of the platforms and admire the mountains & sea coast.  "...platforms *overlooking* the mountains..." would be more idiomatic.

Comment: That's not idiomatic English to me (Aus). I'd say "overlooks" or "looking out over".

Answer (score 0):

In this sentence "looking on" means that from the observation platforms, you can see the mountains and the Black Sea Coast.

To reword the sentence:

> It spans 439 meters and includes observation platforms that face in the direction of the mountains and the Black Sea Coast.

[I looked online for the various uses of "look on"](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/look-on) but I found no evidence of it being used in the same way as your example sentence.

I believe that the person who wrote this sentence meant to write "looking out on" which is a common phrase meaning ["to be oriented in a certain direction."](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/look+out+on)

Here are examples of "look out" and other phrases used in the same context that are more common.

> [From the windows on the observatory floor 5m below the ocean surface,
>   you can **gaze out at** the sea.](http://www.busena-marinepark.com/english/observatory.html)
>
> [...the Octagon Room... is well known to
>   Londoners from the great north window which **looks out** straight
>   over the river...](https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=AecMAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA125&lpg=PA125&dq=the%20observatory%20looks%20out%20at&source=bl&ots=GnY0mFqVy9&sig=9Hps2DSYSL3KG3vwanq-Sjt612E&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiqu4q2h7jWAhWLxrwKHSVzDi0Q6AEIOzAE#v=onepage&q=the%20observatory%20looks%20out%20at&f=false)
>
> [The window **looks out to** this view here.](https://www.tripadvisor.com/LocationPhotoDirectLink-g187870-d564785-i18192225-Almaviva_House-Venice_Veneto.html)
>
> [The house **looks out on** a tennis court.](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/look+out+on)
>
> [The apartment **overlooks** the Hudson.](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/look+out+on)